# Set calendar class instance with the values provided in edit-text

Tags: android, date, calendar

I am creating one application which requires calendar instance containing date and time entered by user.

I've done half of the task by getting values from date and time picker and set it to `edittext` but now how to create calendar instance having same date and time provided in `edittext`.

```
Edittext for Date having value as : `01/03/2018`
Edittext for Time having value as : `12:50`
```

Any help will be appericated.

Comment: I store the year, month, day, etc. components separately, and then create a new calendar object using these saved values.

Comment: how'd you do that with the date in edittext only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I assume that you have date and time data in the exact format of your question.  If so, then one option is to build a timestamp string and then use a `SimpleDateFormat` to convert to a `Date`.  Finally, set the time of a `Calendar` instance using that date.

```
String editText1 = "01/03/2018";
String editText2 = "12:50";
String ts = editText1 + " " + editText2;

String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = sdf.parse(ts);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

### Demo